# In Mysql workbench I have deleted some rows of data without auto commit

Tags: mysql

In Mysql workbench I have deleted some rows of data without auto commit.But now how I can rollback that?I closed and reopened the workbench still data which I have deleted without auto commit has not been rollbacked.

Comment: Those rows are gone. You need to restore your backup.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name But the point is DML clauses like update,delete can be rolled back provided if you dont commit it.Even I had disabled auto commit function in workbench.

Comment: I guess MySQL (or MySQL Workbench) commits when closing the connection. Or you don't use a storage engine that supports transactions.